# Custom initialisation with NSMutableArray in Swift

Tags: swift, initialization

I have a custom `scrollView init` as below in Swift

```
class CustomScrollView:UIScrollView,UIScrollViewDelegate {

private let unitLabelWidth:CGFloat = kScreenWidth / 3
private let displayedUnits:NSMutableArray?

init(frame: CGRect,unitData:NSMutableArray,scrollType:Int) {

    super.init(frame: frame)

    unitData.addObject("")
    unitData.addObject("")

    self.pagingEnabled = false
    self.delegate = self
    self.scrollIdentifier = scrollType
    self.displayedUnits = unitData
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

As you can see, "`unitData`" is a `NSMutableArray` parameter passed and I am adding some objects to the Array in my custom `init`. It's a very simple one.

Now when I am creating objects of this `scrollView`  class, I am getting output which I am not able to comprehend.

Take a look at below code

```
func unitCreation(){
     let units:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(objects:"Unit1","Unit2")
     let unitLabelWidth = kScreenWidth / 3

    let fromUnitScroll = CustomScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, kScreenWidth, ScrollHeight),unitData: units,scrollType:1)
    mainView?.addSubview(fromUnitScroll)


    println(units)

    let toUnitScroll = CustomScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0, fromUnitScroll.frame.origin.y + ScrollHeight * 3, kScreenWidth, ScrollHeight),unitData: units,scrollType:2)
    mainView?.addSubview(toUnitScroll)
}
```

I have an array constant called "`units`" with two objects "`UNIT1`" and "`UNIT2`". When I pass "`units`" to create object "`fromUnitScroll`",data passed is `["UNIT1","UNIT2"]`

Now I am printing the "`units`". Here is where I see weird result. I am expecting to see printed output as `["UNIT1","UNIT2"]` as in the original assignment but what I see is `["UNIT1","UNIT2","",""]`.

Objects added in a custom init method is reflected in the println statement.

I am passing "`units`" as parameter to custom init method and I am not able to get why the addition of objects `init` method is reflected in "`unitCreation`" method

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because NSMutableArray is a class for Swift and as such is passed by reference. Any modifications in the `init` functions will modify the original array. Were you using Swift arrays, which are passed by value, you would not observe this.